# Excel VBA merge/combine columns with same name

Tags: vba, excel

My project work has an issue similar to the one described below.

My dataset is like this
[image]

What I want is like this (LAST COLUMN)
[image]

What I have is many columns of same name like "Is_paid", "Job". 
What I want is to create a new column "Tot", Which combines all these "Is_Paid" and "Job" in a special manner like,

1. Combine all "Is_Paid" column into "Is_Paid_total"
2. Combine all "Job" column into Job_total
3. And the code format is (Not correct)

   ```
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   Dim MyWorksheetLastColumn As Byte

   MyWorksheetLastColumn = Worksheets(1).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   Worksheets(1).Cells(1, MyWorksheetLastColumn + 1).Value = "Tot_Employment"



   Dim rngTemp As Range

   Set rngTemp=Cells.Find("*",SearchOrder:=xlByRows,SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

   With rngTemp


   For Each cel In Range(Cells(1, 1), rngTemp)

   '****************MERGING STEPS**********************  

   If cel.column(Is_Paid_total)="NonPaid" then

    Tot=Is_Paid

    else Tot=Job_total
   ```

End If
next Cel
End With
End Sub

Step 3 will be in a for loop

I dont know how to merge/combine to get Is_Paid_Total and Job_Total. 
Also I know the if statement I have written is wrong. Please help me to tackle this problem.

Comment: Why not just loop through the rows looking for "nonpaid" and placing that in the column, otherwise looking for the second non-blank and placing that in the column?

Comment: May I ask why this needs to be done with VBA?

Comment: I tried all permutations and combinations. And I miss something. Can you pls write in coded form?

Comment: @chancea I have similarly 10-20 files and I have to do the same actions repeatedly. Also my vba program has some other actions too. Thats y

Comment: Would there ever be a time when the "is_paid" column would say "NonPaid" and there be a "job" listed, say in the case of a volunteer?

Comment: Same question as of chancea, why do you need VBA?? Besides the rules you described in your example you always get the rightmost value, please post other examples too if exist, or confirm if correct to get the rightmost data

Comment: @AbdulShiyas Well I won't post this as an answer then but I was able to make that last column by just using `=INDEX(D3:I3,MATCH("*",D3:I3,-1))` and autofilling down.  Maybe we can utilize this within the `Application.Worksheetfunction` or `Evaluate` methods...

Comment: @cliff :) Good thought.

Comment: If that is a consideration, and assuming that you would still want the "total" to display "NonPaid", then you could go with `=IF(OR(D3="NonPaid",F3="NonPaid",H3="NonPaid"),"NonPaid",E3&G3&I3)` Otherwise @chancea 's answer works great.

Comment: @Clif Instead of using column_reference D3,F3,H3 etc, we would like to use column name "Is_Paid" . Because in the real datasheet we cannot exactly mention the column_references (also error can happen if we edited the data set by adding/deleting a column before D3,F3,H3).

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that someone can give you a better answer, however the best way I can think of to meet the criteria in your last comment is to set the data up as a table like so:[image]

The formula for the "Total" column is:

`=IF(OR([@[is_paid]]="NonPaid",[@[is_paid2]]="NonPaid",[@[is_paid3]]="NonPaid"),"NonPaid",[@Job]&[@Job2]&[@Job3])`

Comment: Can I get this using vba ?

Comment: Not sure about that, hopefully someone else will be able to comment on or answer that question.

Answer (score 2):

i have a different formula but the idea is almost the same:

your last column should have this formula

```
IF(ISERROR(MATCH("NonPaid",$A2:$G2,0)),OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW($D2),MATCH("Paid",$A2:$G2,0))),0,1),"NonPaid")
```

you need to adapt it to meet your columns, in my exampl my last column with data is G so that formula is on column H.

i think you can also use it in vba using the range().formula = "=......" 
and then using the filldown for all your range