# Excel VBA: Can we refer a column by its name?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to refer a column by its header name.

Currently column is 4th one and header name is "Preference". 
And the column consists of "Yes" or "No"

5th column header is "Reason"
And it is filled only when "Preference" column is "No"

My code is

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Integer
Dim MyWorksheetLastRow As Byte
Dim MyWorksheetLastColumn As Byte

MyWorksheetLastRow = Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
MyWorksheetLastColumn = Worksheets(1).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Worksheets(1).Cells(1, MyWorksheetLastColumn + 1).Value = "Result"
For i = 2 To MyWorksheetLastRow
If Cells(i, 4).Value = "Yes" Then
Cells(i, MyWorksheetLastColumn + 1).Value = Cells(i, 4).Value
Else: Cells(i, MyWorksheetLastColumn + 1).Value = Cells(i, 5).Value
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

What I want is instead of Cells(i,4) , I want to call the it by column header example: Cells(i,"Preference").
Because I won't the column number of "Preference" in prior. And I use excel vba because I have to deal 20-30 similar files.

Comment: Not as an inherent function as it's not really a heading, it's just the data in cell A1 or B1 or C1 etc etc. What you could do though is maybe set them up as variables at the start? A small routine to populate the column number by finding the value should do it. example you could have a variable called Preference and assign the value of the column it is found in. Then you could use Cells(i,Preference)

Comment: You can use this to find the column number: Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Preference", Range("A1:F1"), 0)

Answer (score 3):

Further to my comments, if you want to do it direct, you would have to do this:

```
cells(i,Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Preference", Range("1:1"), 0)).
```

Comment: Thank you Dan. Suppose I am having columns viz : Preference,Reason,Preference ,Reason,Preference,Reason ... , what can we do? I want to combine/merge all "Preference" and all "Reason" . Any method to do it? Then we can apply your answer.

Comment: Not sure I understand you Abdul, can you post a little sample data to your original post?

Comment: Dan, this is my actual question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621785/excel-vba-merge-combine-columns-with-same-name

Comment: @Gary's Student    I tried by adding another column "Prefernce". It took only first "prefernce" column

Comment: @AbdulShiyas  The problem with using the same name for more than one column is that the code may pick the wrong column.....consider using *Preference1, Preference2*, etc

Comment: Yes. I know. Unfortunately, I am working in a project that cleanses datasets. All those datasets are similar and problem is all of them having issues of same column name.. Is there any other way?! Pls go through this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30621785/excel-vba-merge-combine-columns-with-same-name

Comment: At run time, how is the code to know that you want a specific instance? It would be simple enough to nest the checking to find X instance but how do we know X?

Comment: hmm.. Is there any way in excel-vba to merge all "Prefernce" columns ? If I got all "Prefence" columns merged, then the work is almost done!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to find the column for X instance. I have put a subroutine in there to call it as an example for you.

```
Sub ColInstanceExample()
Dim MyColInstance As Long
MyColInstance = ColInstance("Preference", 2) 'Pass in what you are searching for and the instance you want to return the column number for
If MyColInstance = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Not Found"
Else
    MsgBox "Found at column: " & MyColInstance
End If
End Sub

Function ColInstance(HeadingString As String, InstanceNum As Long)
Dim ColNum As Long
On Error Resume Next
ColNum = 0
For X = 1 To InstanceNum
    ColNum = (Range("A1").Offset(0, ColNum).column) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(HeadingString, Range("A1").Offset(0, ColNum + 1).Resize(1, Columns.Count - (ColNum + 1)), 0)
Next
ColInstance = ColNum
End Function
```

Comment: dan, is there any way merge columns ?

Comment: I just got busy at work so can't write this for you but I will give you the logic and have a go at it, post back if you get stuck. Use my code to find the first instance. then for each row loop through the headings and if you find a column that matches update that first column to be its own value & the value of the newly found cell then clear the found cell value and continue on to the next occurence. It will not be super fast because it is cell level (for each column in each row) but it will work. Like I said give it a go and post back if you get stuck. This will merge all to first instance

Comment: I am new to VBA. I didn't understand completely. Anyhow Thank You much