# How to exit for loop in excel-vba

Tags: excel, vba

My dataset is like this

[image]

I want to make them

[image]

Please look at the first row.

My code is

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim MyColInstance, i As Long
  Dim MyWorksheetLastColumn As Byte
  MyWorksheetLastColumn = Worksheets(1).Cells(1, columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

  For i = 1 To MyWorksheetLastColumn
    MyColInstance = ColInstance("Preference", i)
    Cells(1, MyColInstance).Value = "Preference" & i

  Next i

End Sub

Function ColInstance(HeadingString As String, InstanceNum As Long)
  Dim ColNum As Long
  On Error Resume Next
  ColNum = 0

  For X = 1 To InstanceNum
     ColNum = (Range("A1").Offset(0, ColNum).Column) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(HeadingString, Range("A1").Offset(0, ColNum + 1).Resize(1, Columns.Count - (ColNum + 1)), 0)
  Next

  ColInstance = ColNum

End Function
```

The problem is while running this code, it shows an error because the for loop is not complete. What can we do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Count1, Count2 As Integer
Dim MyWorksheetLastRow As Byte
Dim MyColInstance, emp_i As Long

For Each Row_Cel In Range("1:1")
If Row_Cel.Value = "Employment" Then
Count1 = Count1 + 1
End If
If Row_Cel.Value = "Job" Then
Count2 = Count2 + 1
End If
Next Row_Cel

For emp_i = 1 To Count1
MyColInstance = ColInstance("Employment", emp_i)
Cells(1, MyColInstance).Value = "Employment" & emp_i
Next emp_i
For emp_i = 1 To Count2
MyColInstance = ColInstance("Job", emp_i)
Cells(1, MyColInstance).Value = "Job" & emp_i
Next emp_i


End Sub

Function ColInstance(HeadingString As String, InstanceNum As Long)
Dim ColNum As Long
On Error Resume Next
ColNum = 0
For X = 1 To InstanceNum
ColNum = (Range("A1").Offset(0, ColNum).Column) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(HeadingString, Range("A1").Offset(0, ColNum + 1).Resize(1, Columns.Count - (ColNum + 1)), 0)
Next
ColInstance = ColNum
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do it this way? It seems to me you are just adding a suffix to your headers in the first row...

```
Sub UpdateColumnHeaders()
    Dim headers As Range, header As Range, suffixes As Range, suffix As Range, i As Integer

    Set headers = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column))
    Set suffixes = Range("A1:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)

    i = 1

    For Each header In headers
        If header = "Preferences" Then
            header = header & suffixes(i)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: No. I have many columns in between "Preferences" which I dont want to distrub

Comment: also pls help me to solve this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633763/excel-vba-can-we-refer-a-column-by-its-name

Comment: See updated code - only adds suffix if header is `Preferences`