# Copying Column by Column Name

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook containing 3 sheets. I want to copy a column from sheet1 to sheet3 by using the column name as assigned in A1, B1 and C1. I can copy the contents by using range. But I couldn't find any way to copy by using the column name like "Name" "Age" or so on. I found the following code on some site which shows error '1004'. Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed.

```
Range("P").Value = 15 .
```

I am very new on excel and VBA. TIA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA: Can we refer a column by its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633763/excel-vba-can-we-refer-a-column-by-its-name)

Comment: Excel does not allow this behavior.  The closest you can get is to follow a practice as recommended in the @MatSnow comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what exactly you are trying to do, as your code for range("P").value doesn't make much sense as you have only defined one half of a cell range. But my best guess is you are trying to copy an entire column based on the header of a table (as you mentioned it was assigned in A1, B1 and C1)?

If this is the case, then this quick macro loops through each header as defined in HeaderRange and if it matches your query, will copy it to Cell A1 in sheet3.

```
Sub CopyCol()
Dim HeaderRange As Range
Dim Query As String

Set HeaderRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C1")
Query = "Name"

For Each hcell In HeaderRange ' Loop through each header cell
    If hcell.Value = Query Then ' If it matches your query then copy entire column
        Range(hcell.Address).EntireColumn.Copy _
        Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1")
    End If
Next hcell

End Sub
```

Hopefully this is a good kicking off point for you.